# Navigate to directory of files in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'd like to store multiple html files in a a folder. I'd like to be able to provide a link to the folder so that the user can pick a html file to view.

The issue is that if I try to navigate to the html file I get this message:

```
The application failed to start.

The application exited during initialization.
```

Which makes me think that shiny is treating it as an app and looking for a ui.R and server.R file. I read somewhere that I need a `www` folder but couldn't find any documentation.

How do I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following link to understand the architecture

https://vimeo.com/rstudioinc/review/131218530/212d8a5a7a/#t=3m42s

Also for quick references:

This cheat-sheet can be helpful

[Cheat-Sheet link](http://shiny.rstudio.com/images/shiny-cheatsheet.pdf)